# Add link to top of product page for checkout

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to add a link that takes the customer straight to the checkout and that scrolls down to the customer details.

When clicking it, it just says "Page cannot be found".
What am I doing wrong?

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'product_links', 1 );
function product_links() { ?>
<div class="links-on-product-page"><b>Go to &#x2794;</b> Shop | <a href="wc_get_checkout_url() . '#customer_details'">Checkout</a> | Support</div>
<?php
}
```

Comment: What URL do you see in browser when you click on link? Have you tried with wc_get_checkout_url() . '#billing_details' ?

Comment: it just turns the url into this: /product/t-shirt-with-logo/wc_get_checkout_url#billing_details'

Comment: you could try: <a href="<?php wc_get_checkout_url() . '#customer_details' ?>">Checkout</a>

Comment: that links back to the product